# Type assertion overlapping is kinda confusing

Tags: typescript

Considering the following interface

```
interface myInterface {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}
```

Why do these two assertions work

```
const varOne = { a: true } as myInterface;
const varTwo = { a: true, b: true, c: true} as myInterface;
```

But not this one?

```
const varThree = { a: true, c: true } as myInterface
```

what are the overlapping rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If type 1 extends from type 2, or type 2 extends from type 1, then typescript will trust your type assertion. But if neither extends from the other, then it's more likely to be a mistake and so typescript brings it to your attention. If you're really really sure, you can tell typescript "yes, i really want to do this" by doing: `{ a: true, c: true } as unknown as myInterface`

```
const varOne = { a: true } as myInterface;
```

This first one is allowed because `myInterface` extends `{ a: boolean }`

```
const varTwo = { a: true, b: true, c: true} as myInterface;
```

This second one is allowed because `{ a: boolean, b: boolean, c: boolean }` extends `myInterface`.

```
const varThree = { a: true, c: true } as myInterface
```

But for this third one `myInterface` does not extend `{ a: true, c: true }`, because it's missing a `c` property, and `{ a: true, c: true }` does not extend `myInterface` because it's missing a `b` property.